# Responsive Site - Load html based on dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Is there any JS library that can help load different html files based on the dimensions? I guess this would be a mixture of responsive and adaptive, not sure if that's kosher.

Basically I want the site to show a different top menu on a phone.

Comment: The whole point of responsiveness is that the same HTML works in all cases, and it's the CSS that does the changes...

Comment: Indeed, see this [Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/what-is-the-best-css-grid-framework) to get an idea of what's out there =)

Comment: Ideally yes, but I'm adapting a site that didn't start as mobile first. The site has some issues where the solution would be much cleaner if the content was swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of arguing with you about how you're approaching the problem, I'll say that yes, there are JS libraries that could help you out.

There's a good writeup about [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) at http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/. This one lets you set callbacks for breakpoints.

Another you might be interested in is [breakpoints.js](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/) which, similarly, will let you write jQuery to be executed at certain breakpoints.

Comment: I tried breakpoints.js first, it's lacking much documentation making it hard to use, and its solution doesn't seem very elegant. Enquire.js is a joy to use though and was simple to get running in a few minutes. The syntax used is very similar to css breakpoints too.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you'd want to avoid doing this with a purely responsive design? You could include both a phone navigation and desktop navigation, then hide/show via CSS based on browser dimensions.

Comment: But what does Google think when it's going through your site and start seeing multiple <nav> tags and other duplicate content?

Comment: It would depend on the content of the navigation I guess. If the navigations are truly identical, then there's really no reason to drop a whole menu and add a whole menu. You could handle the differences in a clever combination of jQuery and CSS. I'd assumed you'd have a different menu for phone and desktop, in which case you'd probably want Google crawling both menus.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Kolink's comment..

But if you want to do this anyway I would suggest [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

You will be able to do something like this:

```
enquire
.register("screen and (max-width:50em)", function() { 
    // Load top menu content 1 via AJAX.
    // Show content menu 1
})
.register("screen and (max-width:40em)", function() {
    // Load top menu content 2 via AJAX.
    // Show content menu 2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal situation is to load just an HTML and change the CSS rules applied to it through responsive design.

If you want to have different HTML versions, then you should redirect to another URL if the request comes from a mobile browser. Look at the following link with different recipes depending on your platform:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/